# Cant paste into TinyMCE on iPad

Tags: ipad, tinymce, paste

Developing an app where I would like to be able to paste from Google Docs or even email for that matter into TinyMCE.

This works in Safari and Chrome but when I try it on an iPad, it simply will not paste...

Anyone experienced this or know what I need to do to make this work?

Thanks!

Comment: TinyMCE is completely build on javascript, is javascipt enabled in safari in your ipad?

Comment: has to be since our whole app is based on jquery mobile and everything works except for that paste thing.

Comment: it seems there was a bug in tinymce paste plugin when design mode was off, this bug was reported in tinymce forums and they have fixed it. kindly check this http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?pid=84335#p84335

Comment: Our design mode is on.  Must be a PhoneGap thing since this works in Safari...thats the only ODD man out.

Comment: Hi @ToddVance, have you solved this?